# Automating adb commands

Tags: adb, shell, scripts

is there a way to run adb shell commands via windows?

I would like to run a batch script such as this

```
adb shell 
mount -o rw,remount /system
exit
```

Currently when i run the batch script it only runs the first command `adb shell`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrong syntax :)

```
adb shell "mount -o rw,remount /system"
```

would do in your case (i.e. passing the command you want to run on the device to `adb shell` in double-quotes; the "exit" is not needed here as it is "implied"), provided your device's ADB daemon runs in root mode. You can even run multiple commands at once this way, e.g.:

```
adb shell "mount -o rw,remount /system && echo 127.0.0.1 foobar.com > /system/etc/hosts && mount -o ro,remount /system"
```

Commands connected with `&&` here, meaning: only execute the next command if the previous one succeeded. If you don't want that dependency, use `;` instead to connect them.

For how to use a multi-line command (so called "[HEREDOC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heredoc)") with Windows (or any other OS), SuperUser is the better place to ask (in case the Wikipedia entry is not sufficient ;)

Comment: Thanks. Do you have anything better than this? Concatenating three commands is not my idea of scripting commands over adb. I would be interested in something like the OP describes - a text file with commands to be run over adb.

Comment: @jww then create a script and run each command separately (with the script stored at your PC), or run the script itself on your device.